# Merging two point data sets with artificial grid cells in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, grids-graticules

I have two datasets. The SCAD has conflict data with the exact latitude and longitude, the other one has the exact coordinates for foreign aid. My research question is, whether foreign aid decreases the likelihood of a conflict. Therefore, I would like to have both data in one dataset and the unit of analysis should be 1km x 1km artificial grid cells. 
In the end I would like to have artificial grid cells as unit of analysis. With the exact coordinates I cannot do any data analysis.

Comment: What have you tried? QGIS comes with grid generators in its vector menu / processing ...

Comment: I found the grid generators but honestly I do not understand how this can help me with my problem. When I add a grid I do not know how to match my two datasets with the grids. Any suggestions are welcome. Please help me :)

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to start googeling for my answer...

Comment: I forgot what kind of geometry those output. If it's lines, intersect the grid with a huge fake polygon to get square poligons. Number them as needed, so you have a separate field in the attribute table. Then just intersect these polygons and both datasets, so the both points get the grid cell id. Which means you can then work with them at the cell level.